# How to setup WebStorm IDE as Git core default editor in Windows?

Tags: windows, git, webstorm

So that I can use `git commit` in terminal and it opens the commit message file in WebStorm and wait for it to close?

Tried `--wait` flag as I used it with VS Code editor in `~/.gitconfig` file. My current content of `~/.gitconfig` is:

```
[core]
#   editor = code --wait
#   It worked with VS Code

    editor = webstorm64 --wait
# Not working! Environment Variable is set correctly.
```

While, I try to ammend commit with `git commit --amend`, it shows this in terminal:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: There was a problem with the editor 'webstorm64 --wait'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Comment: That setting should have been correct, were there any other error messages anywhere? Are you able to run `webstorm64 --wait <somefilename>` in the terminal where you run `git commit`?

Comment: @joanis No other error messages. `webstorm64 --wait <somefilename>` works.